ServiceNow Cloud Observability (Lightstep) to "at" @ someone in Slack
For a ServiceNow Cloud Observability (Lightstep) alert, we configured it to be sent to a large Slack channel.
However, when the alert is triggered, one specific individual needs to be "@" "at" "pinged" in Slack.
Therefore, we used the construct:
Some descriptions which is going to end up in Slack channel with many people.

For tihs alert this person should be notified <@John Doe> @John Dow @1234 <@1234>

Please see screenshot

We tried directly @John Doe, adding < >, using the Slack ID instead, hoping it would ping the person.
The alert just displays the name, but the person does not receive the notification.
Question:
How to properly notify the person, what to write in the LightStep description?
